# How do I represent an "empty object" for MongoDB .NET Driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to retrieve index statistics using the MongoDB .NET Driver.

I have tried the following variations of my pipeline

- `var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$indexStats", BsonNull.Value)) };`
- `var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument { {"$indexStats", "" } } };`
- `var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument { {"$indexStats", null } } };`
- `var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument { {"$indexStats", BsonNull.Value } } };`
- `var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument { {"$indexStats", "{ }"} } };`

which is passed to the query

```
var stats = await db
    .GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName")
    .AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(statsPipeline);
```

With the exception of the one containing `null`, which resulted in an `ArgumentNullException`, I have received the exception

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command aggregate failed: The $indexStats stage specification must be an empty object.

How do I change my query such that the `$indexStats` stage specification is indeed an empty object?

Comment: I have no experience with MongoDB at all, but try an actual empty (anonymously typed) object: `new {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one worked:

```
var statsPipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$indexStats", new BsonDocument())) };
```